# GWT 2.5 SelectionCell binding with custom object instead of String

Tags: gwt

I'm new in GWT, I have a question. I want to create an SelectionCell that hold a List of Javascript object instead of List of String. For ex: I have a List of State objects which extends from JavascriptObject.

publi class StateModel extends JavaScriptObject{

```
    protected StateModel(){ }

public final native String getStateName()/*-{
    return this.name;
}-*/;

public final native String getStateAbbreviation() /*-{
    return this.abbreviation;
}-*/;
```

}

from the server, I will get the list of statemodel objects. Now I want to create a dropdown box that will pass the list of statemodel and set display field for dropdown box. And if I call getSelectedObject then I will receive selected StateModel object that return from SelectionCell. Anyone has any idea?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You can get your list of objects, and then create a List of Strings from it (either state names or abbreviations), and pass this list to the SelectionCell. It's only a few lines of code, so I don't think that looking for a different solution is worth it.